# Composer module doesn't contain a .info file

Tags: 7, composer, .info

So I am quite new to Drupal and I was hoping someone experienced could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Essentially, I have Drupal 7.5 linked to my website, but I am having problems installing the [Composer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer) using the control panel.

Whenever I attempt to add the module by either URL or a local download, Drupal claims that it doesn't include a .info file. Which, from what I can tell after unpacking it and inspecting its contents, is true.

So, I was wondering if the lack of a .info file is a problem on my end (likely) or just a case of the Composer devs forgetting to include it (unlikely).

Hopefully someone will be able to help out.

Answer (score 1):

The project you linked to is a Drush extension, not a module, and only compatible with Drupal 8.

So it makes sense that you can't install it as a module into a Drupal 7 site ;)

Answer (score 0):

As [the project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer) says, that is not a module, but a Drush extension.

> Since this is Drush extension that works across all versions of Drush, it doesn't need a different release for each different Drupal version. Hence this just being an 8.x project.

In fact, it does miss the .info (or .info.yml) file necessary to Drupal to recognize it as module, but it also misses a .module file.

There are module that are also Drush extensions, but this is not the case. It is hosted as module on drupal.org simply for the fact drupal.org doesn't have *Drush extension* as project type, so you need to necessarly select *module* if you want to host a Drush extension on drupal.org.